# Does Hinduism claim God to be benevolent?

Tags: gods

I wanted to ask if Hinduism claims God to be benevolent or not because If he is benevolent then there wouldn't be any suffering in the world.

Comment: Benevolence is a perceived quality. Tigers do not consider God as benevolent when they cannot eat men. Men consider God benevolent when they are not eaten by tigers. So, who should God be benevolent to? This world is only God's sport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

God Is neither benevolent nor malevolent.God is an neutral entity who created this system in which we live according to Our Karma and free will.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Krishna says in the Bhagavad Gita that he protects the righteous:

https://vivekavani.com/bhagavad-gita-chapter-4-verse-7-8/

> यदा यदा हि धर्मस्य ग्लानिर्भवति भारत ।
> अभ्युत्थानमधर्मस्य तदात्मानं सृजाम्यहम् ॥४-७॥

> परित्राणाय साधूनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् ।
> धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय सम्भवामि युगे युगे ॥४-८॥

The verse in Roman script—

> Yada yada hi dharmasya glanirbhavati bharata
> Abhythanamadharmasya tadatmanam srijamyaham

> Paritranaya sadhunang vinashay cha dushkritam
> Dharmasangsthapanarthay sambhabami yuge yuge

The meaning of these two slokas is—[1]

> Whenever there is decay of righteousness, O Bharata,
> And there is exaltation of unrighteousness, then I Myself come forth ;

> For the protection of the good, for the destruction of evil-doers,
> For the sake of firmly establishing righteousness, I am born from age to age.